# Tkinter Image Button with transparent Background Python

Tags: python, tkinter, button, background

I´m really new to python and trying to get a touch gui running with python.

I designed it in figma and now I´m in to get the buttons running.

The problem is, that Im not gonna get a transparent background of the button. Is there an other way instead of tkinter?

My last try would be using the coordinates of a mouse click and just use the icons as background. But then I´m not getting this "click"-animation without making many new images for the background.

This code is running indepoendently and shows my problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

window = Tk()
window.title('title')
window.geometry('1024x768')

Background = PhotoImage(file="Background.gif")
Background_Label = Label(window, image = Background)
Background_Label.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

ButtonMapLoad = Image.open('ButtonMap.png')
ButtonMap = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ButtonMapLoad)
tk.Button(window, image=ButtonMap, borderwidth = 0 , highlightthickness = 0, relief = "flat", overrelief = "flat").pack(padx = 100, pady = 20)


mainloop()
```

The picture shows, how my button looks like.

Button on background:

[image]

I just want a nice GUI thats not looking like 1998 :-(

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

William

Comment: You can remove the background of the image.

Comment: The background ist removed. It's transparent, but tkinter is adding a grey rectangle.

Comment: @WillGIam add `relief='flat'` as a keyword argument to the `Button` class: `Button(..., relief='flat')`, also about this: _I just want a nice GUI thats not looking like 1998 :-(_, well, [`Tcl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) (which is the base of `tkinter`) is pretty old, that is why it may look like from 1998, tho actually the first release was in [1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) so what did you expect? it is like 33 years old, so either you have to really figure out how to make it not look like that or use a different library like PyQt5 or Kivy

Comment: @WillGIam however `tkitner` has the great advantage of being quite easy and pretty powerful (although for working with extremely high quality graphics is not what you may want to use it for) in the sense that you could create almost anything GUI and quite quickly (another benefit) (otherwise it is not thread safe so sometimes it may be hard to display large amounts of data quickly but you can work around that too in some way), for comparison I could compare it to `flask` and other libraries are `django`, both are great depending on what you need/want and can do almost the same thing

Comment: @Matiiss as you see I already did that. 

I already read that, but wasnt sure about which library to go with. At last every of them is "just" putting an image inside the window.

So you say I should better go with PyQt5 for example? Kivy is not working with Pycharm for my (didnt figure out why).

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @WillGIam I have only experience with `tkinter` so I can't tell if it is better to go with `PyQt5`, again it depends on what you want, I think `tkitner` is much more simple and you can create pretty great GUIs with it (I once saw one made with `tkinter` that I never would have guessed was made with it because it looked very good and very much not like 1998), `PyQt5` on the other hand can be used to make apps for mobile devices and stuff but it might be a bit more complex, but again I don't have experience with it so I can suggest that you try out both and then choose which one you like better

Comment: @WillGIam get on my profile I uploaded an image of a project. Does this look like 1998?

Comment: Since you use `figma`, you can try [`tkinter designer`](https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer).

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you. I got Kivy running after a few hours and getting good results.

Now I´m getting new problems - I dont think there is a way to embed the mobile google maps navigation in my gui? :D Didnt see that coming.

Comment: @Atlas435 Well, as I said, it depends on the pictures youre using for the gui.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I tried that on 3 different systems. The designer has uploaded different versions under different names and nobody knows which documentation is for which project, because the code he gives there is different. So I did it manually now.

Comment: @WillGIam actually now that I have noticed the image you posted, I could have suggested using `Canvas` and `.create_image`, if the image has transparent background, it will be transparent on the Canvas too so you can kinda use the `Canvas` as the "root" and it is also possible to `.tag_bind` the specific image to say a button press to act like a button, but I see you have managed to do sth with Kivy so good luck, as far as I know there are at least two great advantages when using it, it has an html like layout manager and it is cross-platform to mobile extent